# Should we have a tag for riddles related to tv or movies?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have recently noticed that we have a "video-games" tag but no "tv-shows" or "movies" tag. Should we have a tag for tv related questions? (e.g. questions found in tv-shows or riddles where you guess the tv-show or movie)

Comment: I'd argue the opposite; why do we need a video games tag in the *first* place? It seems to me that it'd simply be better to merge all tags like that into the [trivia] tag. That was we also avoid spoilers.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Mithrandir, except that I'm not sure [trivia] is the right one (because there are other sorts of trivia, and knowing those feels kinda different from knowing about video games and TV shows); perhaps something like [popular-culture] or [media]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistaken: **we do have a [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies) tag**, with exactly 100 questions at the time of writing.

I'm not sure if a separate [tv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) tag would be useful. Knowledge about movies and knowledge about TV shows usually come together, so I'd say both of these could be covered by a single tag, maybe the existing [movies](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies).

(I would disagree with the commenter who said all such tags should be merged into [trivia](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivia). It's **very useful** for solvers to know what kind of trivia they'll be expected to know. For example, I directly skip any question tagged [video-games](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games), but I'll have a look at any question tagged [literature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature). Please keep these tags separate! Avoiding spoilers isn't an argument, because it's the OP's choice how much information they want to reveal in the puzzle.)